# Division by zero occurred in the expression in derived column ssis

Tags: ssis

I want to calculate a derived column in ssis

```
X= (A-(C-D)*100)/(c-D)
```

but when I executed the package it give me this error

```
Division by zero occurred in the expression
```

How to solve this issue ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using the ISNULL IFF expressions? That should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it I just had to make filter on divisors to be non null.and voila works !
thanks